# basic objects: ORA-00932 when INSERT object type data

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Part of my homework. I know this is quite basic, but it is not so intuitive for me.
I create this:

```
    CREATE TYPE Address_typ AS OBJECT (
      AddressNo  NUMBER,
      Street    VARCHAR2(64),
      PostCode  VARCHAR2(9),
      Town      VARCHAR2(64)
      );
    /

    CREATE TYPE Customer_typ AS OBJECT (
      CustNo         NUMBER,
      customer_name  VARCHAR2(64),
      VAT_NO         VARCHAR2(18),
      Address_ref    REF Address_typ
      );
    /

CREATE TABLE Address_table OF Address_typ;

CREATE TABLE Customer_table OF Customer_typ
(Address_ref SCOPE IS Address_table);
```

this insert works:

```
INSERT INTO Address_table VALUES(Address_typ(1,'Strumykowa 5','65-001', 'Zielona Góra'));
```

and one below is not (with empty Address_table):

```
INSERT INTO Customer_table VALUES(Customer_Typ(1,'PPUH ZZPD', '12345678901', Address_typ(1,'Strumykowa 5','65-001', 'Zielona Góra')));
```

How should I insert correctly into Customer_table

Comment: should the Customer_typ be relative?...  I guess not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way will work:

```
INSERT INTO Customer_table
VALUES(Customer_Typ(1,'PPUH ZZPD', '12345678901', (select ref(a) from address_table a where a.AddressNo = 1)));
```

Comment: Thanks, strange that I didn't figure it out myself.